# rails observer custom callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, transactions, callback, observer-pattern

1. How to implement custom call_back and then register method into observer?
2. If we use transaction into the model, is after_create is triggered for every single record inside the transaction or is triggered after transaction is finished?

Using Rails 3

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

1. You add the method, say, :after_something to your observer, and then issue notify_observers(:after_something) in your code in model. The method will receive the model instance as a parameter.
2. after_create is called for the observer of the class which instance was created. Each instance.